# Why we need to write WHEN OTHERS THEN exception at the last - Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I know that in Oracle PLSQL Exception handling, WHEN OTHERS THEN exception needs to be written at the end of all the exceptions, irrespective of user defined or oracle predefined ones.
Oracle document is not sufficient to answer the 'HOW' part.
Please explain in detail.
Link I found:- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#LNPLS00708
Useful snippet from the same:- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#LNPLS00708

Answer (score 1):

"How" part? Did you mean to say "why" part instead?

Here's why:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_ename emp.ename%type;
  3  begin
  4    -- this raises TOO-MANY-ROWS
  5    select ename
  6      into l_ename
  7      from emp
  8      where deptno = 10;
  9  exception
 10    when others then
 11      dbms_output.put_line('others');
 12    when too_many_rows then
 13      dbms_output.put_line('too many rows');
 14  end;
 15  /
  when others then
  *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PLS-00370: OTHERS handler must be last among the exception handlers of a block
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your links, `WHEN OTHERS THEN` is optional, which means you can include it but you don't have to.

Comment: Yes I know this is optional and we can exclude it also. But when we write any exception, say when no data found below when others then, it doesn't allow so. I am asking why it is not allowed?

Comment: Look at the exception clause as a specialized form of the case statement. Then "when others" corresponds to the "else" condition. Now image attempting to write "Case else... when... "